# Extending footer to edges of window (left and right)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, footer, css-tables

When developing my website at http://filmblurb.org, I'm having trouble with my footer. For my footer, I'm trying something new, I'm doing a table that stretches to the outer edges of the browser window, with the rest of the content (i.e. the posts, jQuery slider, etc.) slimmer than the width of the footer.

For my footer I have a table within a table, both of which contain one cell each. I want the outer table to stretch to 100% of the browser window and I'm planning on using this by placing some sort of background image. In front of that and in that table, I'm planning on putting my footer content (i.e. sitemap, contact information, copyright information, etc.) in this cell, which will span 960 px. This width is also equal to the width of the rest of my content on my website's home page.

If someone can please help me out on this, I would greatly appreciate it.  (If it helps, I'm using Wordpress 3.2.1.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you need to do is place the `div#footer` in its proper position.

So, remove `position:absolute;` and `height:1em;`

Then add a `float` and a `width`

```
#footer {
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Right now your `div#footer` is inside your `div#wrap`, which is keeping it centered and restricted from spanning the entire window width.

Remove it from the `#wrap` and place it under that `div` if you want it to span the entire page.

Finally, do not use `table`s for non-tabular data.  Use `div`s instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice you not to float the footer  to the left if you make the width 100%. Look at what you do.

Add this code to your css and every element will be centered except if you individually float them left or right.

- {
      margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  }